# Get the bounding box of an SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm loading an SVG document dynamically and then need to extract the location of certain elements in the SVG before it is displayed.  Is there some way to get eg the `x,y` co-ordinates of a `rect` element, with all transforms on that element and its parents applied?

Suppose my SVG looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="matrix(1.4142057, 0, 0, 1.4142057, 0, 0)">
    <rect x="25" y="50" width="100" height="200"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I happen to be using d3 to load this:

```
    d3.xml('/static/node.svg')
        .then(data => {
            var x = d3.select(data)
                .select("rect")
                    .getBBox().x;
            console.log(x);
        });
```

But `getBBox()` always returns all-zeros in this context, it seems.  Is there a way to apply all the transforms to an element's parameters without actually displaying the image?

A way to collate all the transforms into a single transform matrix (without manually parsing all the transforms) and apply it to an arbitrary vector would do.

**Edit**: `getCTM()` also returns `null` when the SVG is not displayed, which is not very useful.

Comment: [getBBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox). Your issues are both in the notes at the top.

Comment: Yes, I know getBBox doesn't do what I want.  I said so in the question.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of that question - but if so, there are still no answers to it.  If you consider that other question answered, this is not a duplicate of it.

Comment: There still is no way, but manually.

Comment: @JavaScript: Okay, thanks.